# Rename file in DocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, swift, file-rename

I have a PDF file in my `DocumentDirectory`.

I want the user to be able to rename this PDF file to something else if they choose to.

I will have a `UIButton` to start this process. The new name will come from a `UITextField`.

How do I do this?  I'm new to Swift and have only found Objective-C info on this and am having a hard time converting it.

An example of the file location is:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/39E030E3-6DA1-45FF-BF93-6068B3BDCE89/Documents/Restaurant.pdf

I have this code to see check if the file exists or not:

```
        var name = selectedItem.adjustedName

        // Search path for file name specified and assign to variable
        let getPDFPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(name).pdf")

        let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        // If it exists, delete it, otherwise print error to log
        if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(getPDFPath)) {

            print("FILE AVAILABLE: \(name).pdf")

        } else {

            print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE: \(name).pdf")

        }
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To rename a file you can use NSFileManager's `moveItemAtURL`.

Moving the file with `moveItemAtURL` at the same location but with two different file names is the same operation as "renaming".

Simple example:

**Swift 2**

```
do {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let documentDirectory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let originPath = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("currentname.pdf")
    let destinationPath = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("newname.pdf")
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(originPath, toURL: destinationPath)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
do {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let documentDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let originPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("currentname.pdf")
    let destinationPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("newname.pdf")
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: originPath, to: destinationPath)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This is moving file from one folder to another, anyways it's working but when there is space in the filename it's not working. **ex: current name.pdf** it's an url space is automatically converting to %20. Is there any other possibulity renaming folder without URL/moving.??

Answer (score 12):

The modern way is (`url` is the file URL of a file in your sandbox):

```
var rv = URLResourceValues()
rv.name = newname
try? url.setResourceValues(rv)
```

Comment: It does work. Your expectations are wrong or your way of testing whether it worked is wrong. This technique changes the file, not the URL!

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk please take away your false comment.

Answer (score 7):

There is an easier way to rename item at any given NSURL.

```
url.setResourceValue(newName, forKey: NSURLNameKey)
```

**Edit - Swift4**

```
url.setTemporaryResourceValue(newName, forKey: .nameKey)
```

Comment: Works on UbiquityContainer URLs as well. You're Welcome :)

Comment: Looks like it's deprecated now.  Use: `url.setTemporaryResourceValue(newName, forKey: .nameKey)`

Comment: Unless I miss something this won't work, it will not rename the file because it is temporary.  As per Apple docs: `Temporary resource values exist only in memory and are never written to the resource’s backing store.` 
The answer by @matt works for me!